# MBF - Calling option not showing in teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, mbf

I have followed the instructions for creating a calling bot with MBF, I have updated the manifest also, still bot not showing the calling option.

[image]

Comment: Hi @kiran, can you once confirm if you have checked both the options given under Calling Bot section in Manifest.
1. My Bot supports Video Call
2. My Bot supports Audio Call

Comment: @saonti ya, i have set both as true

Comment: Could you please share the manifest?

Comment: are you still facing the issue? Then could you please share your manifest?